# How to ensure views respect Safe Area in SwiftUI while parent view ignores it efficiently in TabView?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm developing an app with a user interface similar to TikTok, featuring multiple tabs, including a full screen vertical scroller tab. In this scroller view, I want the background to extend beyond the safe area, covering the full screen. However, I also need some overlaid views to stay within the safe area.

Currently, I'm using `GeometryReader` for this layout. The challenge arises when I switch to the second tab for the first time. The background seems to rebuild, which is not ideal for performance, especially if the background is a video.

To illustrate, I've created a simplified version of this issue. It features a background with a randomly generated color and a blue box representing the safe area content. The problem is noticeable when the background color changes upon swiping to the next tab, indicating that the view has been rebuilt(I guess). How can I prevent this view from rebuilding when switching tabs, or is there a more efficient workaround for this scenario?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedIndex: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            TabView(selection: $selectedIndex) {
                PageView()
                Text("2nd tab")
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}

struct PageView: View {
    @State private var paddingValue: EdgeInsets = EdgeInsets()
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack(spacing: 0){
                    ForEach(0..<10){post in
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(randomColor())
                            .containerRelativeFrame ([.horizontal, .vertical])
                            .overlay {
                                SafeSectionView()
                                    .padding(paddingValue)
                            }
                    }
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .onAppear {
                if paddingValue == EdgeInsets() {
                    paddingValue = geometry.safeAreaInsets
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func randomColor() -> Color {
        return Color(
            red: Double.random(in: 0...1),
            green: Double.random(in: 0...1),
            blue: Double.random(in: 0...1)
        )
    }
}

struct SafeSectionView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.blue)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```